Make a pcap file in python with two udp packets with different timestamps
I have a piece of code for making pcap files taken from here:
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/612847/generate-a-quick-and-easy-custom-pcap-file-using-p
port = 9600

#Custom Foo Protocol Packet
message =  ('01 01 00 08'   #Foo Base Header
            '01 02 00 00'   #Foo Message (31 Bytes)
            '00 00 12 30'   
            '00 00 12 31'
            '00 00 12 32' 
            '00 00 12 33' 
            '00 00 12 34' 
            'D7 CD EF'      #Foo flags
            '00 00 12 35')     


"""----------------------------------------------------------------"""
""" Do not edit below this line unless you know what you are doing """
"""----------------------------------------------------------------"""

import sys
import binascii

#Global header for pcap 2.4
pcap_global_header =   ('D4 C3 B2 A1'   
                        '02 00'         #File format major revision (i.e. pcap <2>.4)  
                        '04 00'         #File format minor revision (i.e. pcap 2.<4>)   
                        '00 00 00 00'     
                        '00 00 00 00'     
                        'FF FF 00 00'     
                        '01 00 00 00')

#pcap packet header that must preface every packet
pcap_packet_header =   ('AA 77 9F 47'     
                        '90 A2 04 00'     
                        'XX XX XX XX'   #Frame Size (little endian) 
                        'YY YY YY YY')  #Frame Size (little endian)

eth_header =   ('00 00 00 00 00 00'     #Source Mac    
                '00 00 00 00 00 00'     #Dest Mac  
                '08 00')                #Protocol (0x0800 = IP)

ip_header =    ('45'                    #IP version and header length (multiples of 4 bytes)   
                '00'                      
                'XX XX'                 #Length - will be calculated and replaced later
                '00 00'                   
                '40 00 40'                
                '11'                    #Protocol (0x11 = UDP)          
                'YY YY'                 #Checksum - will be calculated and replaced later      
                '7F 00 00 01'           #Source IP (Default: 127.0.0.1)         
                '7F 00 00 01')          #Dest IP (Default: 127.0.0.1) 

udp_header =   ('80 01'                   
                'XX XX'                 #Port - will be replaced later                   
                'YY YY'                 #Length - will be calculated and replaced later        
                '00 00')
                
def getByteLength(str1):
    return len(''.join(str1.split())) / 2

def writeByteStringToFile(bytestring, filename):
    bytelist = bytestring.split()  
    bytes = binascii.a2b_hex(''.join(bytelist))
    bitout = open(filename, 'wb')
    bitout.write(bytes)

def generatePCAP(message,port,pcapfile): 

    udp = udp_header.replace('XX XX',"%04x"%port)
    udp_len = getByteLength(message) + getByteLength(udp_header)
    udp = udp.replace('YY YY',"%04x"%udp_len)

    ip_len = udp_len + getByteLength(ip_header)
    ip = ip_header.replace('XX XX',"%04x"%ip_len)
    checksum = ip_checksum(ip.replace('YY YY','00 00'))
    ip = ip.replace('YY YY',"%04x"%checksum)
    
    pcap_len = ip_len + getByteLength(eth_header)
    hex_str = "%08x"%pcap_len
    reverse_hex_str = hex_str[6:] + hex_str[4:6] + hex_str[2:4] + hex_str[:2]
    pcaph = pcap_packet_header.replace('XX XX XX XX',reverse_hex_str)
    pcaph = pcaph.replace('YY YY YY YY',reverse_hex_str)

    bytestring = pcap_global_header + pcaph + eth_header + ip + udp + message
    writeByteStringToFile(bytestring, pcapfile)

#Splits the string into a list of tokens every n characters
def splitN(str1,n):
    return [str1[start:start+n] for start in range(0, len(str1), n)]

#Calculates and returns the IP checksum based on the given IP Header
def ip_checksum(iph):

    #split into bytes    
    words = splitN(''.join(iph.split()),4)

    csum = 0;
    for word in words:
        csum += int(word, base=16)

    csum += (csum >> 16)
    csum = csum & 0xFFFF ^ 0xFFFF

    return csum


"""------------------------------------------"""
""" End of functions, execution starts here: """
"""------------------------------------------"""

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'usage: pcapgen.py output_file'
        exit(0)  

generatePCAP(message,port,sys.argv[1])

The above code works for single packet from the payload message.
message =  ('01 01 00 08'   #Foo Base Header
            '01 02 00 00'   #Foo Message (31 Bytes)
            '00 00 12 30'   
            '00 00 12 31'
            '00 00 12 32' 
            '00 00 12 33' 
            '00 00 12 34' 
            'D7 CD EF'      #Foo flags
            '00 00 12 35') 

I want to add a second packet to the pcap file with payload
message2 =  ('f1 b1 a0 08'   #
            '01 02 00 00'   #
            '00 00 12 30'   
            '00 00 12 31'
            '00 00 12 32' 
            '00 00 12 33' 
            '00 00 12 34' 
            'e7 CD EF'      #
            '00 00 12 35') 

with a different timestamp (delayed by 1.52345 second from the first packet). In the Time column of Wireshark viewer I must see 1.52345 for the second packet. I tried to change the part
bytelist = bytestring.split()  
bytes = binascii.a2b_hex(''.join(bytelist))

like bytelist.append(bytelist) and all. But in vain.Packet is not valid as mentioned by Wireshark.

The code snippet shared seems to be creating the packet in binary/hexadecimal and then writing to a pcap file. But timestamp is not written by in the packet, it is stamped by the OS packet capture mechanism.
If you need to add time, you can read the file you have created via scapy and add time, then write to the file again.
Untested code -
from scapy.utils import PcapReader, wrpcap
packets = PcapReader('filename.pcap')
pkt = packets[0]  # Since we know it has only singly packet.
pkt2 = pkt  # Duplicate packet.
pkt2.time = pkt2.time + delay  # Add your delay here.
wrpcap('filename.pcap', pkt2, append=True)

